# Windows Store Universal 8.1 App How to Bind to data in Shared area

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm Porting my working Phone8 app to a Universal one (Store and Phone 8.1)

Class NewsList extends ObservableCollection.
I bind to it in a Listview in Xaml with ItemsSource="NewsItems" using markup like this:

```
xmlns:news="clr-namespace:BowlsGroup.Data.News"

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <news:NewsList x:Key="NewsItems"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

This worked for Phone8.

I created a new Universal app and placed class NewsList in the Shared area.

With the above dictionary resources now in a Page.Resources block, the above code no longer works. I get: 
"The name NewsList does not exist in the namespace BowlsGroup.Data.News".

Which is not the case.
I tried doing the markup in App.xaml but same problem.

Question is:  How to bind to data located in the Shared project area?

The NewsList declartion part:

```
namespace BowlsGroup.Data.News
{
    public class NewsList : ObservableCollection<NewsItem>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
xmlns:news="clr-namespace:BowlsGroup.Data.News"
```

to

```
xmlns:news="using:BowlsGroup.Data.News"
```

Check this blog post for the difference in referring to namespaces in WinRT vs Silverlight:
http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2012/08/18/windows-store-apps-winrt-xaml-vs-silverlight-xaml/

Comment: Tried that already, gives the error:   The name NewsList does not exist in the namespace using:BowlsGroup.Data.News".

Comment: @RatatatRichie can you also post the definition for the NewsList class?

Comment: edit the post .. and do not post the entire class source, just the namespace and the class name declaration ...

Comment: Also, have you tried other classes, which are not derived from ObservableCollection? I am using converter classes from a shared project and they work without a problem

Comment: @RatatatRichie I created a blank application with the NewsList class in the Shared project and referring it from a phone page. Check it out: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B37CC7D5117B9A1B!27508

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jogy for your help. Months ago I had a similar problem which was cured
when other anomalies were sorted. Sometimes I've had to close the solution and reopen it.
I cant actually pinpoint what kind of errors in the c# code caused this latest problem.

When building the code, the only errors reported were of the type:
"The name blah does not exist in the namespace tiddleypom".
I tried so many things yesterday, including removing some Silverlight-ridden code.
(I am porting a phone8 app to the universal 8.1 solution).

i think it goes like this;
With the offending xmlns markup I get the one error. 
When I remove the markup I see other errors. On fixing these and reinstating the markup
the projects build without errors.

Sorry about the vague answer, thanks again.